# What happens to the difference between the limit order and executed order

Tags: limit-order, robinhood

Say I place a limit order at 100$ for IBM using Robinhood. While waiting for it to be executed, the price goes down, and the order is executed at cheaper than my limit, say 99$.

My question is, what happens to that 1$? Does Robinhood keep the difference?

Comment: It would be helpful if you specified the exact details of your position if you own the stock. Stop loss order?    If not, what are you trying to do?  Buy it at a lower price?

Answer (score 2):

If you place a limit buy order for $100 and it's executed at $99, then you only pay $99. You keep the remaining $1.

If you place a limit sell order for $100, it will not be executed at $99.

Comment: Buy when you place an order, the money is locked up by the Robinhood. You saying they will refund 1$ in case they fill it cheaper?

Comment: It's only locked so you don't use it a second time in parallel. They don't 'take' it from you; they just keep you from using it for other actions.

Comment: You can confirm this by placing a limit buy order at a price somewhat above the current price. It will be executed instantly but it will be executed at a lower trade price than you specified in the order. You'll keep the difference.

Comment: @EmrahSarıboz That's right. You'll get that $1 back.